# Qualtrics Javascript not saving response

Tags: javascript, keycode, qualtrics

I'm using some code in javascript and having a hard time getting it to save responses. No matter how I tweak it or what I do, I can't seem to see the variable in the actual data file. My script looks like this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    if ($('NextButton'))
        $('NextButton').hide();
    if ($('PreviousButton'))
        $('PreviousButton').hide();

    var that = this;
    Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function(e) {
        var choiceID = null;
        if (e.keyCode == 49) { //'1' was pressed
            choiceID = 1;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 50) { //2'' was pressed
            choiceID = 2;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 51) { //'3' was pressed
            choiceID = 3;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 52) { //'4' was pressed
            choiceID = 4;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 53) { //'5' was pressed
            choiceID = 5;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 54) { //'6' was pressed
            choiceID = 6;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 55) { //'7' was pressed
            choiceID = 7;
        }
        if (choiceID) {
            that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
            that.clickNextButton();
        }
    });
});
```

The survey runs thought this code fine, but no `choiceID` variable is made in my data file. I've tried similar other variations; they all go through the screen fine, but no variables in my data file.

Any help would be very appreciated! I'm totally stumped.

Comment: If the code is javascript, why is the tag `java`?

Comment: choiceID isn't an embedded variable, so it won't be in the response data. choiceID is the selected choice in a multiple choice question. Look in your data file to see there is an answer to the question this script is attached to.  The value should be the selected choiceID (as long as the question is a single select multiple choice and choice ids are 1 through 7, which they usually are ... but not necessarily).

Comment: I've looked in the data file, but there's nothing even resembling 1-7. I have some questions in the survey that ask for reaction times, and all I'm getting are those.

Comment: Depending on how you are looking at the data, you could be seeing the choice text instead of the id. For example, if this script is attached to Q1, look to see if you have answers to Q1. If you do, the script is working. If you don't have data, then I think your choiceIDs are wrong. In that case, look at your recodes. If you haven't recoded the recodes will be the choiceIDs.

Answer (score -1):

The code works fine, but variables defined in Javascript aren't stored in the output automatically. You must put the value into an embedded data field.

1) Go to the Survey flow and define a new embedded data field called for instance choiceID. Its value can remain empty.

2) Insert following line to your javascript above the line cotaining  `if (choiceID) {`.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("choiceID", choiceID);
```

This will send the value of your variable choiceID to the embedded data field of the same name.